# How do I insert formula in between sentences?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I insert formula in between sentences? For example, in A1 i want to write:

```
Welcome =C1
```

So `=C1` will replaced with anything in `C1` cell.

If in `A1` I write `Welcome`, then in B2 I write `=C1` then I will get `Welcome =C1`, but they are in separate cells and have a space between them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `CONCATENATE` function.

In cell `A1` put:

```
=CONCATENATE("Welcome "; C1)
```

It will concatenate the string `"Welcome "` with the string written in cell `C1`.

See the result below:

[image]

You can also try Adam's suggestion of inserting the following in `A1`:

```
="Welcome " & C1
```

The result will be the same:

[image]

If you want to insert more names just insert the cell reference where the name is written (`C1`, `D1`, `E1`, etc) in your function separated with the ´&´ character.

See below and example:

[image]

**Note:** I inserted a blank space (`" "`) to separate the names, however your can insert `","` or anything else.

The same thing can be done using the `CONCATENATE` function:

In cell `A1` insert:

```
=CONCATENATE("Welcome "; C1; " "; D1; " "; E1)
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please let me know how i can also insert more, i mean, welcome C1 D1 to E1

Comment: @khalid, you can concatenate as many times as you like, so you can add more linkages either with `=CONCATENATE("Welcome ";C1;D1;E1)` or `="Welcome " & C1 & D1 & E1`.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly but if I do, you simply enter the following formula in A1:

```
="Welcome " & C1
```

That will give you "Welcome Adam" in A1 if C1 contains "Adam".